# Retrieve values from dynamically added selects using Jquery in PHP

Tags: php, jquery-ui

I wanted to chain 3 selects and I got it working using this code.
http://jsfiddle.net/FJFFJ/1/

```
<div id="filter">
            <a id="clone" href="#">+</a> <a id="remove" href="#">-</a>

        </div>
        <div id="template">
            <select class="pais">
                <option value="1">Argentina</option>
                <option value="2">Chile</option>
            </select>
            <select class="provincia">
                <option value="1" class="1">San Juan</option>
                <option value="2" class="1">Mendoza</option>
                <option value="3" class="2">La Serena</option>
                <option value="4" class="2">Santiago</option>
            </select>
            <select class="ciudad">
                <option value="1" class="1">Rawson</option>
                <option value="2" class="2">Godoy Cruz</option>
                <option value="3" class="3">Coquimbo</option>
                <option value="4" class="4">Chiñihue</option>
            </select>
        </div>
```

The issue I now have is, how do I fetch the selected values from each dropdown in PHP?
For example, the above creates 3 select boxes when the page is opened.
When I click on "+" button and add more rows of selects, how do I fetch the values from all selects which were added dynamically?

this is what I did now? but still doesnt work.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    foreach($_POST['semester'] as $sem){
        echo $sem;
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/normalize.css">


  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/result-light.css">



      <script type='text/javascript' src="http://www.appelsiini.net/download/jquery.chained.mini.js"></script>


  <style type='text/css'>
    #template{
    display:none;
}
  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
$(window).load(function(){
$(function() {

    // Form element cloning
    var i = 0;
    $('#clone').click(function() {

        $('#template').clone().appendTo('#filter');
        $('#filter #template').attr('id', 'duplicate' + i);
        $('#filter div:hidden').show();


        chainItWithId(i);
        i++;
    });
    $('#remove').click(function() {
        $('#filter > div').last().remove();
    });

    $('#clone').click();
});

function chainItWithId(id) {
    $('#duplicate' + id + ' .department').chained('#duplicate' + id + ' .semester');
    $('#duplicate' + id + ' .subject').chained('#duplicate' + id + ' .department');
}


function chainTemp() {
    $('#template .department').chained('#template .semester');
    $('#template .subject').chained('#template .department');
}
});//]]>  

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="filter">
            <a id="clone" href="#">+</a> <a id="remove" href="#">-</a>

        </div>
        <form name="request" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        <div id="template">
            <select class="semester" name="semester[]">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
            </select>
            <select class="department" name="department[]">
                <option value="EEE" class="1">EEE</option>
                <option value="ECE" class="1">ECE</option>
                <option value="MECH" class="2">MECH</option>
                <option value="CSE" class="2">CSE</option>
            </select>
            <select class="subject">
                <option value="1" class="EEE ECE">S1</option>
                <option value="2" class="ECE">S2</option>
                <option value="3" class="MECH">S3</option>
                <option value="4" class="CSE">S4</option>
                                <option value="5" class="MECH">S5</option>
                <option value="6" class="CSE EEE">S6</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make them array, `<select name="pais[]" class="pais">` etc ... and make a form .. to submit.

Comment: Whatever you do, make sure you **always** uniquely identify each `select`, `option` etc. Make a form in which you insert all these generated selects and later use a submit button that does a `POST` call.

Answer (score 0):

add an id to your select box, for instance
changes in html:

```
 <select class="provincia" id="provincia" name="provincia">
            <option value="1" class="1">San Juan</option>
            <option value="2" class="1">Mendoza</option>
            <option value="3" class="2">La Serena</option>
            <option value="4" class="2">Santiago</option>
        </select>
```

get selected value using jquery

```
var first = $("#provincia option:selected").text();
var second = $("#pais option:selected").text();
var third = $("#ciudad option:selected").text();
```

send those values to ajax call.now you can get in php.

if you dont know the id values then do it by 
serialize the form data using jquery serialize and it to php by using jax call.

example

```
$( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
event.preventDefault();
console.log( $(this).serialize() );
```

});

Comment: thanks, but I would like to get this in PHP, If I add another row of selects using jQuery there will be 2 selects. I need values of both the selects to be fetched in PHP so that I can save in DB.So if I add the id attribute to the select like id = provincia[], will this work?

Comment: I dont think this is the answer he is looking for. While clicking + button, another set of 3 select boxes should appear and so on. And how to get the values of all those dynamically...

Comment: you can get it by adding name to select box $_REQUEST['provincia']

Comment: Roy MJ is inline with what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

1) You should wrap it all in  tag. Use method='post' or method='get' and action='path/to/php_script.php' attributes of

2) You should use name attributes for your selects like

```
<select name="ciudad" class="ciudad">
```

3) Add subbmit button inside 
    
4) After submiting in php_script.php you can use $_GET['select_name'] or $_POST['select_name'] arrays (depend on form method) to get a list selected value