# Chaining selects with Chosen

Tags: jquery-chosen

I'm trying to chain selects with [Chosen](https://github.com/harvesthq/chosen) and [Chained](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/chained) but I'm not sure if I'm implementing .chosen().change() correctly or if the error I'm getting is a bug.

Here's what I've got:

```
<select id="Inputfield_date" name="date" data-placeholder="Select event date">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="WA">WA</option>
<option value="QLD">QLD</option>
<option value="VIC">VIC</option>
<option value="NSW">NSW</option>
<option value="SA">SA</option>
</select>

<select id="Inputfield_code" name="code" data-placeholder="Response code">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="601" class="WA">601</option>
<option value="602" class="WA">602</option>
<option value="402" class="QLD">402</option>
<option value="403" class="QLD">403</option>
<option value="301" class="VIC">301</option>
<option value="302" class="VIC">302</option>
<option value="201" class="NSW">201</option>
<option value="203" class="NSW">203</option>
<option value="501" class="SA">501</option>
</select>

$('#Inputfield_date').chosen().change(function() {
    $("#Inputfield_code").chained("#Inputfield_date");
});
```

which gives me *Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded*.

EDIT: I now also need to hide/show another field if a particular option is chosen and I'm not sure what the correct approach is for that.

Comment: this is an example on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18441118/retrieve-values-from-dynamically-added-selects-using-jquery-in-php

Comment: I'm not seeing Chosen used in that example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the example from the Chained documentation I've put up an [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koenpunt/Fzh9G/).

And it is actually fairly simple, just initialize Chained and Chosen as you would normally do, and then trigger the `chosen:updated` event if one of the selects changes:

```
var selects = $('#Inputfield_code, #Inputfield_date');
$('#Inputfield_code').chained('#Inputfield_date');
selects.chosen({width: '300px'})

selects.on('change', function(){
    selects.trigger('chosen:updated');
});
```

**EDIT:**

For your second question I've updated the fiddle a bit: http://jsfiddle.net/koenpunt/Fzh9G/2/

Chosen sends which option is selected alongside the change event, so checking if a specific option is selected is easy:

```
$('#series').on('change', function(event, data){
    // First check if data exists, because if the change event
    // isn't triggered by Chosen `data` is undefined
    if(data){ 
        if(data.selected == 'a5'){
            $('#submit').hide();
        }else{
            $('#submit').show();
        }
    }
});
```

As you will notice, if you select 'Audi' and 'A5' the button will disappear.